# Remove strings with punctuation from list

Tags: python, list

I am learning Python and I am extracting some datas in a csv.
My goal is to put one column, for example 'names' into a list.
This, I know how to do it.

After, I would like to delete inccorect names into the list. For example :

```
lists = [Anderson, Byrne, Clark, Cooper, Davies, Evans, +Miller, Moore, Thom@s, W!lson]
```

and I want :

```
lists = [Anderson, Byrne, Clark, Cooper, Davies, Evans, Moore]
```

Because some names has `+` or `@` or `!` inside. I don't want to change the character, I want to delete those names.

I tried, a classic if else but it didn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code you've tried

Comment: I assume your list members are strings? and should have ' or " around each one?

Comment: `list` is a kind of dangerous variable name.

Comment: `list` is a built-in object in Python, and the examples you posted are NOT valid lists.

Comment: I know that list is a build-in object, I will correct my text, sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.isalpha`:

```py
names = [
    'Anderson',
    'Byrne',
    'Clark',
    'Cooper',
    'Davies',
    'Evans',
    '+Miller',
    'Moore',
    'Thom@s',
    'W!lson'
]

only_names = [n for n in names if n.isalpha()]
# only_names = list(filter(str.isalpha, names))

print(only_names)
```

Comment: It can be good to write up code for purpose of understanding, imo this is most Pythonic, uses proper idioms and not re-inventing the wheel. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha

Comment: This is a much better way of testing it using `str.isalpha()`.

Answer (score 2):

For filtering valid names:

```
names = ["john", "mich@el", "suraj"]
valid_names = [name for name in names if name.isalpha()]
print(valid_names)

Output: ['john', 'suraj']
```

As asked by OP in the comments below, for filtering valid emails with valid usernames:

```
emails = ["john.doe99@some.com", "m!chael@other.com", "su_raj.sinha@mail.com"]
valid_emails = []
allowed = "._"

for email in emails:
    username = email.split("@")[0]

    for ch in allowed:
        username = username.replace(ch, "")
    
    if username.isalnum():
        valid_emails.append(email)

print(valid_emails)

Output: ['john.doe99@some.com', 'su_raj.sinha@mail.com']
```

Comment: It works very good ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression for it. Python supports a regular expression module, called [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

For example, a name consists of only alphabets.
You can use list comprehension and re to filter only valid names as follows:

```py
import re

names = [
    'Anderson',
     'Byrne',
    'Clark',
    'Cooper',
    'Davies',
    'Evans',
    '+Miller',
    'Moore',
    'Thom@s',
    'W!lson'
]

only_names = [n for n in names if re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$", n)]

print(only_names)
# ['Anderson', 'Byrne', 'Clark', 'Cooper', 'Davies', 'Evans', 'Moore']
```

For more information, check the [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all elements in the list are strings, you can get the result you want with:

```py
names = [
    'Anderson',
     'Byrne',
     'Clark',
     'Cooper',
     'Davies',
     'Evans',
     '+Miller',
     'Moore',
     'Thom@s',
     'W!lson'
]

names_filtered = [
    name for name in names if ''.join(c for c in name if c.isalpha()) == name
]
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is is running without creating an additional list.
it just modifies the list in-place by using a for loop:

```
lst = ['Anderson', 'Byrne', 'Clark', 'Cooper', 'Davies', 'Evans', '+Miller', 'Moore', 'Thom@s', 'W!lson']
for ind in range(len(lst) -1, -1, -1):
    if not lst[ind].isalpha():
        del lst[ind]
print(lst)
```